# jquery .trim() with textboxes

Tags: jquery, textbox, trim

In a different post I made, someome explained that to check for blank values in text boxes and textareas you should use .val() with $.trim to check for blank values. For e.g.,

```
if($.trim($("#textboxid").val()) == "") {
    //do something
}
```

Can someone explain to me why we need to trim anything here? Are there hidden spaces or carriage returns in textboxes?

Comment: That will depend on what you are trying to achieve. Don't take this as a rule of thumb.

Comment: My guess is the author of that post was trying to catch users who intentionally enter spaces, in which case `val()` would not be an empty string, but trimmed it would be caught.

Comment: The example was probably based off the fact that a user could fake an entry by adding a space. So rather than doing multiple checks for spaces this removes them and checks for a blank input. It's actually a pretty good idea if that's all you wanted to validate.

Comment: use === instead of == (javascript the good parts) , you could take this as a rule of thumb :)

Answer (score 2):

As with lots of things in JavaScript (and programming in general), it's all about writing *robust* and *maintainable* code.  This code is simply more tolerant of errant user input.  If a user puts a space in there and then forgets about it, visually they won't be able to tell.  This will take care of that scenario by checking to see if your field contains merely whitespace.

However, it might not be appropriate in all scenarios!

Further, as long as we're talking "robust and maintainable" code, be sure to use explicit equivalency operators rather than truthy/falsey tests:

```
$.trim($("#textboxid").val()) === ""
```

Answer (score 1):

trim is so that if the user put in a space, it doesn't treat it like a value.  Using trim with make a value of
`" "`  become `""`.

Answer (score -1):

It is application-specific whether someone wants to trim the textboxes or not. In general it is hard to see and hence detect.